# how to show different language characters in git log?

Tags: macos, ssh, locale, lang

Here is what I am seeing now in my git log:

```
commit d0ed97d243eaf905b03244a4d1ba6af26213e4ad
Author: some guy <someone@somesite.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 3 11:22:06 2013 +0900

<E3><83><98><E3><83><83><E3><83><80><E3><81><AE><E3><83><A6><E3><83><BC><E3><82><B6><E3><82><A2><E3><82><A4><E3><82><B3><E3><83><B3><E8><A1><A8><E7><A4><BA>
```

the commit is made by some Japanese characters.

I've already changed my LANG env to ja_JP.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8, ja_JP.eucJP:

```
$ export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
```

but nothing worked.

Hope someone knows and give me some points.
Thanks.


UPDATE (solution 1):

Finally, I managed to show those Japanese characters by commenting out the line `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in `/etc/ssh_config` file in the local environment(which is MacOS).
But I don't think I solved this issue. I think I just cut off the way of sending the settings of LANG to the server side(CentOS). So basically, the LANG settings in the local env is still messing up because when I tried `$ locale` in the local env(mac), it shows the following settings:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Which is obviously a inappropriate setting.
I am still undering goggling...


UPDATE (solution 2):

I finally find the solution to the "locale" issue, 
here is the link I find:[How to fix locale issues in Mac OSX terminal](http://yzisin.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/how-to-fix-locale-issues-in-mac-os-x-lion-terminal/)
Thanks for all the help from all the people here.

Comment: It seems to be utf8 characters. Have you tried `git log --encoding=UTF-8`?

Comment: what is your git version?

Comment: @dyng but UTF-8 should be the default?

Comment: @dyng: for me, using `--encoding=UTF-8` did not make any difference. When locale is set to `C`, `git log --encoding=UTF-8` would still print <xx> chars.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Yes, it is default but isn't guaranteed here. And from git manual, if an encoding head has been set in commit object, `git log` will use that rather than utf8. @mvp Locale is a good clue, but OP has tried setting `LANG` to `ja_JP.UTF-8` and it still doesn't work, so I have no good idea.

Comment: @dyng: I tried `git log --encoding=UTF-8` but it didn't work.

Comment: @mvp: my git version is 1.7.11.1

Comment: @cRazYpi: how is your last updated solution any different from what I suggested in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16954919/1734130)? My advice was to fix locale to `en_US.UTF-8`, which is exactly what your linked solution does.

Comment: @mvp: I don't know, it just didn't work when I tried your answer. I noticed that in the solution link there is "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" but in your answer is "export LC_ALL=", maybe it's the problem. It was two months ago and I can't really remember the situation. If your answer worked, how could I not choose it to be a correct answer instead of typing so many words in the update of my post... you know, I won't get any profit from that. Anyway, I think your answer helps me to find the correct solution so I gave you an UP.

Comment: @cRazYpi: I guess this is OS/X bug to require explicit `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. In Linux, all you need to do to set proper UTF-8 locale is `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` - it automatically sets all `LC_*` variables so everything just starts working out of the box. To make it even easier, on most recent Linux distros it is default setting.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that your system supports UTF-8 properly. Most Ubuntu and Fedora boxes do. If you are using terminal or ssh session, make sure that your ssh client is configured to use `UTF-8` all the way. For example, if using `putty`, be sure to configure it to use `UTF-8` encoding in preferences - it is not a default setting.

I have relatively old git version 1.7.7.6 on this Fedora 16 box, but it seems to work just fine, as long as I set my locale properly:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ git log
commit 40b8cb9fc58775826a511c5338370f7fd1454481
Author: some guy <someone@somesite.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 5 22:57:10 2013 -0700

welcome
привет
ヘッダのユー
```

It still works the same if I set locale to Japanese:

```
$ export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
$ git log
commit 40b8cb9fc58775826a511c5338370f7fd1454481
Author: some guy <someone@somesite.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 5 22:57:10 2013 -0700

welcome
привет
ヘッダのユー
```

But it breaks if I set locale to Posix (`C`):

```
$ export LANG=C
$ git log
commit 40b8cb9fc58775826a511c5338370f7fd1454481
Author: some guy <someone@somesite.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 5 22:57:10 2013 -0700

welcome
<D0><BF><D1><80><D0><B8><D0><B2><D0><B5><D1><82>
<E3><83><98><E3><83><83><E3><83><80><E3><81><AE><E3><83><A6><E3><83><BC>
```

For reference, this is what working locale should look like:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Thanks, @mvp, you helped me a lot to found s solution. See my UPDATE upper. Now I am just trying to fix the wrong setting in my local env. Hope you can give me a few more tips.