# How to solve git messy code?

Tags: git, android-studio

I am using "Git log" in Android Studio.

Why my terminal command showed messy code?
And how to solve it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHwdf.png]

Answer (score 0):

Launch your Android Studio from a session where your LC_* variable are correctly set.

See "[how to show different language characters in git log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16952391/6309)" as an example.

If the Android Studio inherit those environment variable, it has a better chance to display unicode characters.